# How to map querystring to action method parameters in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a url `http://localhost/Home/DomSomething?t=123&s=TX`  and i want to route this URL to the following action method

```
public class HomeController
{
   public ActionResult DoSomething(int taxYear,string state)
   {
      // do something here
   }
}
```

since the query string names does not match with action method's parameter name, request is not routing to the action method.

If i change the url (just for testing) to `http://localhost/Home/DomSomething?taxYear=123&state=TX` then its working. *(But i dont have access to change the request.)*

I know there is `Route` attribute i can apply on the action method and that can map `t` to `taxYear` and `s` to `state`.

However i am not finding the correct syntax of Route attribute for this mapping, Can someone please help?

Comment: Why not just `public ActionResult DoSomething(int t,string s)`?

Comment: You can always use `Request.QueryString["t"];` inside your controller action

Comment: If you can change the Action's parameter names then you should just do as Stephen Muecke suggested and change the names to match the query string names

Comment: The query string has absolutely nothing at all to do with (built-in) routing. The MVC framework uses [value providers](http://www.dotnetpiper.com/2014/06/smart-working-with-custom-value.html) to supply query string information to the MVC pipeline. You can change its behavior by creating your own value provider. See [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37329603/181087).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Option 1

If Query String parameters are always *t* and *s*, then you can use Prefix. Note that it won't accept *taxYear* and *state* anymore.

```
http://localhost:10096/home/DoSomething?t=123&s=TX

public ActionResult DoSomething([Bind(Prefix = "t")] int taxYear, 
   [Bind(Prefix = "s")] string state)
{
    // do something here
}
```

### Option 2

If you want to accept both URLs, then declare all parameters, and manually check which parameter has value -

```
http://localhost:10096/home/DoSomething?t=123&s=TX
http://localhost:10096/home/DoSomething?taxYear=123&state=TX

public ActionResult DoSomething(
    int? t = null, int? taxYear = null, string s = "",  string state = "")
{
    // do something here
}
```

### Option 3

If you don't mind using third party package, you can use [***ActionParameterAlias***](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ActionParameterAlias/6.0.0). It accepts both URLs.

```
http://localhost:10096/home/DoSomething?t=123&s=TX
http://localhost:10096/home/DoSomething?taxYear=123&state=TX

[ParameterAlias("taxYear", "t")]
[ParameterAlias("state", "s")]
public ActionResult DoSomething(int taxYear, string state)
{
    // do something here
}
```