# c# webapi with query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes, query-string

I have WebApi baed web service like:

```
public class ControllerName : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/ControllerName/{p1}/{p2}/{p3}/{p4}/{p5}")]
    public string GetItemByNameAndId(string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4, string p5)
    {

    }
}
```

This type request is working:

> host/api/ControllerName/1/2/3/4/5

But I want this type of request:

> host/api/ControllerName/&p1=1&p2=2&p3=3&p4=4&p5=5

and I receive error like:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (&). Which steps must be followed? Any changes in config files,
>   any attributes etc.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: cor, that's a broad question.. What have you done so far and why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: But, you've declared the route to expect /1/2/3/4/5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969112/how-to-map-querystring-to-action-method-parameters-in-mvc

Comment: the error is because you first param has &p1 and not ?p1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do not want the first type of request

```
host/api/ControllerName/1/2/3/4/5
```

Then remove them from the route template

```
[RoutePrefix("api/ControllerName")]
public class ControllerName : ApiController {
    //GET api/ControllerName?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3&p4=4&p5=5
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetItemByNameAndId(string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4, string p5) {
        //...
        return Ok(someResult);
    }
}
```

So that the query string version will map to the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

too many parameters is not a good design， and it can be refact to a parameter class.

```
public class ParamClass {
    public string P1 { get; set; }
    public string P2 { get; set; }
    public string P3 { get; set; }
    public string P4 { get; set; }
    public string P5 { get; set; }
}
```

and in your api controller, use it like this:

```
//GET api/ControllerName?host/api/ControllerName?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3&p4=4&p5=5
[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult GetItemByNameAndId([FromUri(PreFix="")] ParamClass param) {
    //...
    return Ok(someResult);
}
```